# output of Fragment shader as a texture

Tags: opengl, shader, jogl

I have a problem with the fragment shader,
this is my situation:

I have a 3d scene with a simple 2d square representing a wall (with "GL.GL_QUADS") in the middle.
I move the virtual camera using the function "glu.gluLookAt".

I implemented a simple fragment shader for the wall that basically changes the color of the wall respect to the distance from the wall to the virtual camera (using dFdx and dFdy).

The problem is that instead of visualize the output of the shader on the wall I would like to store the output in a buffer or in a texture.

I tried with "gl.glBindFramebufferEXT" but in this case the output was the entire rendering of the virtual scene, not just the output of the shader referred to the wall.

So how can I "extract" only the output of a fragment shader referred to a GL_QUADS without "extract" all the rendered scene?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set up an ortho projection and render only the quad needed to the FBO (or just a screen aligned quad). Then, render the scene with the contents of the FBO bound as a texture.

Comment: it doesn't work. If I use "gl.glOrtho" the quad is always at the same distance from the camera thus the color doesn't change.

Comment: Can't you pass in the "distance" from the wall as uniform and have the shader generate the color that way?

Comment: no, I use another method with the functions dFdx and dFdy, the quad doesn't have a single color, each pixel can have different one.

Comment: It **should** be possible to rewrite your shader so it can take the world-space position of the camera and generate this procedural texture.

Comment: there are other projects that use this method..http://silverspaceship.com/src/svt/ , http://epubl.ltu.se/1404-5494/2010/009/LTU-HIP-EX-10009-SE.pdf , http://www.ub.tuwien.ac.at/dipl/2010/AC07808876.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're mixing two things up. I didn't say you can't procedurally generate the texture. I just said that you'll need to provide the shader the "distance from the wall" or whatever other parameters it needs via uniforms, instead of relying on the GLSL constructs. Your question should probably be rephrased as - how can I modify this shader to work without dFdx/dFdy, or something similar.

Comment: But I would like to use dFdx/dFdy because it's possible...but I don't know how :) I don't exactly use the distance of the camera but the dFdx/dFdy in order to retrieve the mipmap. The shader is correct, I can visualize the output (it a gridlines that represents different level of details) but I don't know how to use that output